# Why Saudia Arabia Consulate's website in the United States (US) require US certification of Power of Attorney document if both are members of HCCH?

Tags: united-states, international, power-of-attorney, saudi-arabia, egypt

Why does the Saudia Arabia Consulate in the United States (US) require US certification of  Power of Attorney document if they are member of HCCH?

> Documents and Powers of Attorney
>
> Notary Public The county clerk of the respective county where the
> notary public is commissioned; the county clerk is normally stationed
> in the court of the specific county where the notary public is
> commissioned by the U.S. Department of State.
>
> Documents must be certified under the seal of the local branch of the
> State Department. Documents must be authenticated by the State
> Department Authentication Division. Fee: Payment must be made, either
> through mofa.gov.sa, or one of the authorized offices. Documents must
> be sent to the Consular Section of the Embassy of the Kingdom of Saudi
> Arabia to the United States of America. https://www.saudiembassy.net/document-certification
>
> CONVENTION ABOLISHING THE REQUIREMENT OF LEGALISATION FOR FOREIGN
> PUBLIC DOCUMENTS (HCCH)
>
> The present Convention shall apply to public documents which have been
> executed in the territory of one Contracting State and which have to
> be produced in the territory of another Contracting State.
>
> For the purposes of the present Convention, the following are deemed
> to be public documents:
>
> a)  documents emanating from an authority or an official connected
> with the courts or tribunals of the State, including those emanating
> from a public prosecutor, a clerk of a court or a process-server
> ("huissier de justice");  b)  administrative documents;  c)  notarial
> acts;  d)  official certificates which are placed on documents signed
> by persons in their private capacity, such as official certificates
> recording the registration of a document or the fact that it was in
> existence on a certain date and official and notarial authentications
> of signatures.
>
> However, the present Convention shall not apply:
>
> a)  to documents executed by diplomatic or consular agents;  b)  to
> administrative documents dealing directly with commercial or customs
> operations.

https://www.hcch.net/en/news-archive/details/?varevent=857

> "The Commission nonetheless wanted to avoid the exclusion, once
> accepted, being given too general a meaning. The qualifier
> "administrative" shows that commercial documents such as contracts and
> powers of attorney are subject to the rules of the Convention.
> "https://www.hcch.net/en/publications-and-studies/details4/?pid=52
>
> https://www.hcch.net/en/instruments/conventions/full-text/?cid=41

I found the same policy for Egypt even though they are also member of HCCH,

"https://egyptembassy.net/consular-services/legalization/commercial-legalization-procedure/"